# .htaccess redirect to subdomain only for homepage (OpenCart)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

I want to redirect from mydomain.com to shop.mydomain.com but I also want to make this redirect work ONLY for the main page. It's an Opencart page so all the pages have urls similar to http://shop.mydomain.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=14 so making a rule for the index file only is a no go from my point of view. Since this project is a code spaghetti and has both OpenCart pages and static pages I need to keep the old URLs (without the subdomain) in working condition.

Looked up similar topics but all of them do the exact opposite thing, redirect from domain to subdomain or do the same thing but render my static pages useless so I ended up in using a very bad temporary method as shown below.

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://shop.example.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=15'" />
```

Thank you very much and I hope I won't get loads of duplicate votes until you read and find something that is truly a duplicate.

Comment: What's in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks
 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Comment: Is `http://shop.example.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=14` your main page? Are you wanting to redirect from that page or exactly `http://example.com/`?

Comment: I want to redirect from http://example.com/ to http://shop.example.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=‌​14. The homepage will be the opencart one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect root to shop.example.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://shop.example.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=14 [R,L]

# Route to PHP files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

To make the redirect permanent, change `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: It redirect to example.com/shop (where the opencart is installed) not to http://shop.example.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=14 :(

Comment: That's not what the rule is instructing, which means that there is another redirect being triggered somewhere. Or perhaps it is a cache issue. But the rule shown above redirects http://example.com/ to http://shop.example.com/index.php.../

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file in the `/shop` directory? If so, what's in it?

Comment: Nope, no .htaccess in that folder.

Comment: I have just tested the redirect, and it is working as intended. Please try with another browser, or clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: That was indeed a cache problem. Thank you very much! You can edit your comment to let others know why it wouldn't work before clearing my cache.

Comment: You're welcome. No need for me to edit the answer, as it does indeed answer the question, and others can see the comments.